# Index IF Greater Than and IF Less than

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a dataset in which I need to index column J1:J30000 IF column BF1:30000 is greater than 94% and if it is less than 101%. I can already get a formula to work to locate projects over budget but I'd like to show those projects that are within 5%, 10% and 20% of their respective budgets.[image: Sample Worksheet]

Comment: So when you want within 5%, does that include 5% under budget and 5% over budget,  or just 5% under budget since all that are over budget will be picked up in the first column?

Comment: One simple method I can suggest you, find out 5%, 10% & 20% of the Budget value & compare it with existing as you did for over budget !! ☺

Comment: What do you mean by "index"?  What, exactly, do you want to do with cells in J when BF is or isn't within the target range?  What about values for which BF is blank?

Comment: I want to list the Project code in column J that has a negative number and then that are within 5%, 10% & 20% of their respective budgets.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your spreadsheet columns, but I will go with the following understanding.

You are looking to generate a list of:

1. All projects that are over budget.  The percentage in column BF will
   be greater than 100%
2. All projects that are greater than or equal to 95% and less than or
   equal to 100% in column BF
3. All projects that are greater than or equal to 90% and less than 95%
   in column BF
4. All projects that are greater than or equal to 80% and less than 90%
   in column BF

I am assuming that you do not want projects that are less than 5% being listed in less than 10% even though they are and gain not listed in 20% even though they are.

having said that, you can use the following equations in BI through BL.

```
Over Budget:

=IFERROR(INDEX($J:$J,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($J$2:$J$16)/(($BF$2:$BF$15<>"")*(1<$BF$2:$BF$15)),$BH3)),IF($BH3=1,"None",""))

Within 5%:
=IFERROR(INDEX($J:$J,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($J$2:$J$16)/(($BF$2:$BF$15<>"")*(BJ$2>=(1-$BF$2:$BF$15))),$BH3)),IF($BH3=1,"None",""))

Within 10%:
=IFERROR(INDEX($J:$J,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($J$2:$J$16)/(($BF$2:$BF$15<>"")*(BK$2>=(1-$BF$2:$BF$15))*(BJ$2<(1-$BF$2:$BF$15))),$BH3)),IF($BH3=1,"None",""))

Within 20%:
=IFERROR(INDEX($J:$J,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($J$2:$J$16)/(($BF$2:$BF$15<>"")*(BL$2>=(1-$BF$2:$BF$15))*(BK$2<(1-$BF$2:$BF$15))),$BH3)),IF($BH3=1,"None",""))
```

I also recommend you rearrange your headers slightly for your within percentage such that your 5,10 and 20 are sitting in cells of their own.  I did that so that in theory you could add 25% 50% 75% in adjacent columns, and all you would need to do is copy your formula in the third column to the right...provide you have your locks ($) set right

[image: POC]